# Is a subset of a relation that is a partial order also a partial order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

I've sat on this question for a while now:

**Question:**

> Suppose that $R$ is a partial order. If we take some subset $S$ of $R$, will it also
> be a partial order? Prove or disprove this.

Now I know the following. For a partial order, the set must follow these criteria.

1. reflective
2. anti-symmetric
3. transitive

So if the relation on a set is a partial order. If we collected any values from that set $R$ and put in set $S$ will that be a partial order?

I believe that the subset is always reflective because a set is always a subset of itself. However I am struggling to prove the other $2$ criteria.

**Example:**

$R = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)\}$

$S = \{(1,1),(2,3)\}$

Subset $S$ is not a partial order from the set of relation $R$? I could use multiple counter examples and proof by cases?

Is this the right way of looking at the question?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, your set $S$ proves that a subset of $R$ need not be reflexive, and hence they need not be partial orders. Just proving that reflexivity sometimes doesn't hold is enough, as no such subset can be a partial order. You don't need counterexamples for any of the other properties (though you could be a complete show-off and find a subset of $R$ that is neither reflexive, transitive, or antisymmetric!).

Comment: So you're saying that no subset can be a partial order? I'm not fully grasping why not. Couldn't you find elements in R that are all 3 such that S holds for all 3 criteria?

Comment: No, I'm saying that **some** subsets of $R$ (e.g. $S$) are not reflexive, and such subsets are not partial orders. Some subsets of $R$ will be partial orders too, but not all of them. Just displaying one example of a subset that is not a partial order (e.g. $S$) is enough to complete the proof.

Comment: Ahh yes I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A subset of a partial order need not always be one. For a simple example, take

$$R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}$$

This relation is a partial order. However, take

$$S = R \setminus \{(1,1)\}$$

The relation is no longer reflexive, and thus not a partial order. In general, if $R$ is a partial order over a nonempty set $A$, then $S_a = R\setminus \{(a,a)\}$ for any fixed $a \in A$ is a subset of $R$ which is not a partial order. (And we know such an $(a,a) \in R$ exists since $A \ne \varnothing$ and $R$ is reflexive.)

---

*...granted, this question is quite old, so I imagine you don't need help now. But hopefully this helps someone in the future, and, if nothing else, gets this question out of the unanswered queue.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $R\subset A\times A$ is a partial order and $B$ is a subset of $A$, then
$$S = R\cap B\times B = \{(a,b)\mid (a,b)\in R,a,b\in B\}$$
is a partial order. This is the best general result you can get.

In your example, let  $R= \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)\}$, where $A=\{1,2,3\}$. If $B=\{1,2\}$, then $S=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}$.

---

Transitivity: Let $aRb$ and $bRc$. We know that $aRc$.

If $a,b,c\in B$, then fine.

If $a,b\in B$ but not $c$, then $aSb$ but not $bSc$. Fine.

Similar if $b,c\in B$ but not $a$.

If $a,c\in B$ but not $b$, then $aSc$. Fine.

Comment: Where is the transitivity in this?

Comment: @FraserGilbert: transitivity holds, see answer.

Comment: If S = (1,1)(1,2),(2,2) then wouldn't transitivity suggest  if 1=2 and 2= 3 then 1=3. But there is no 3 in this?

Comment: @FraserGilbert: The relation is restricted to elements in $B$.

Comment: Therefore its not transitive since we need  a 1,3?

Comment: So to add on its not a partial order because it is not be transitive?

Comment: In the example the relation $S$ is transitive. Only when the premise is satisfied, the conclusion need to be satisfied. And here you have only $1S2\wedge 2S2\Rightarrow 1S2$.

Comment: Sorry I don't quiet get it. S does not have pairs that make it transitive. i.e. there is no 2,3 or 1,3 to make this transitive. This is where I am getting confused.

Comment: I get it now sorry. Will all subsets be a partial order?